# Weird deletions in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a web game in which an alliance can have multiple members. This is represented by a foreign key field on each member's class (seeing as a member can only be part of one alliance).

I've been getting weird instances of worlds and alliances being deleted. I narrowed it down to where I was sure the worlds were getting deleted only because the alliances were, so I removed the cascade deletion. However, I still cannot figure out for the life of me *why* the alliances are being deleted in the first place.

I overrode the custom delete method like so:

```
class Alliance(models.Model):
    ...
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mail.send_mail('Alliance Deletion', '%s has been deleted.' \
           % self.alliance_name, 'from@email.com', ['to@email.com'])
        super(Alliance, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, at least one alliance has been deleted where I did not get an email sent to me. I gather this is because I must be calling delete() from a QuerySet, but I have been over my code with a fine-toothed comb and there is precisely one occasion where I call delete() on any alliance instance, and it's not over a QuerySet.

Is there a way to track down what is causing this, or to find out what function has executed the delete of an object?

Comment: by default Django Foreign Key deletion has a cascade effect and it deletes the object containing the ForeignKey. It's handled by on_delete method.  I'm wondering if you overrode the wrong method? I've never personally tried this, so hopefully somebody has more information.  I read about on_delete here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: 'so I removed the cascade deletion'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I was calling `delete()` on a M2M relation when I should have been calling `remove()`.